# How to split one Keras model among multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I work on medical imaging so I need to train massive 3D CNNs that are difficult to fit into one GPU. I wonder if there is way to split a massive Keras or TensorFlow graph amongst multiple GPUs such that each GPU only runs a small part of the graph during training and inference. Is this type of distribute training possible with either Keras or TensorFlow?

I have tried using `with tf.device('\gpu:#')` when building the graph but I am experiencing memory overflow. The logs seem to indicate the entire graph is still being run on `gpu:0`.

Comment: Have you looked into keras' multi GPU support? https://keras.io/utils/#multi_gpu_model

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I have, but I think that is for parallel training (like running duplicates on different GPUs) for faster training, correct me if I am wrong tho.

Comment: Maybe this article will help? https://medium.com/@willburton_48961/how-to-use-distributed-tensorflow-to-split-your-tensorflow-graph-between-multiple-machines-f48ffca2810c

Comment: no i think he (and me ) are looking to split triaining on multiple GPUs (graphics cards ) ON THE SAME MACHINE.